# Convert.ToDateTime retorna o dia anterior

Tags: c#

Usando C#, quando eu executo isso:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("Wed, 20 May 2015 01:36:39 +0000")
```

Ele me retorna isso:

```
{19/05/2015 22:36:39}
    Date: {19/05/2015 00:00:00}
```

Como faz para ele retornar o valor correto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que o `Convert.ToDateTime` está a converter a data original em UTC para uma data local.

Verifica se a propriedade `Kind` é igual a `DateTimeKind.Local`.

Se for, tens que converter a data para UTC novamente

```
date = date.ToUniversalTime();
```